# Html.ActionLink equivalent of a specific URL format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-routing, html.actionlink

I want to use `Html.ActionLink` to return an anchor tag with href like */Product/22/Product-Name*, where *Product* is my controller name and *22* is my id and *Product-Name* is my title.

In my global.asax, I have set the following route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "ProductRoute", // Route name
  "Product/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I tried using following code

```
@Html.ActionLink(model.Name, null, "Product", 
             new { id = model.Id, title = model.Name.Replace(" ","-") }, null)
```

but it yields *Product/Browse/22?title=Product-Name*. This code is in *Browse* View returned by *Browse* action of *Catalog* controller and that's why it picks up the *Browse* in between.

Strangely, the same code works fine in the *Index* View returned by *Index* action of the *Home* Controller. What's the reason for this difference? . Am I missing something or this is a bug in Asp.net MVC3.

What Should I do to achieve my stated URL format. For the meantime, I am using this code

```
<a href="/Product/@product.Id/@product.Name.Replace(" ","-")">@product.Name</a>
```

Comment: You also can't have an optional parameter come before a required parameter in a route definition. So you can remove id = UrlParameter.Optional from the route definition.

Comment: the routes fine...there is nothing wrong with it....I am just unable to get the Html.ActionLink right

Comment: Have you tried using Html.RouteLink instead?

Comment: I don't know much about it, but i tried @3nigma code a few secs ago and it worked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have defined the custom route before the default route and try

```
@Html.ActionLink(model.Name,
                  "Index",
                 new {controller="Product", id = model.Id, title = model.Name.Replace(" ","-") }, null)
```

the first parameter is the DisplayName, second the `ActionResult`'s name and then the RouteValues

Comment: Thanks!! It works. You have given the ActionName, but still it doesn't show up, why so. Also, why my HTML.ActionLink code worked fine in Home's Index view

Comment: the actionname doesn't show up because its not part of your Route, the route contains the controller/id/title, as long as it worked for you at the Index page i cant say what could be the reason...

Comment: hmm....thanks mate....I suppose this might be bug in MVC3, otherwise why would the same code show different results.... :-) ...